# VS Code messing with quotation marks and spaces in paths

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mpi

I configured VS Code for running MPI codes from the "Run task" button, but somehow it puts a " right next to the gcc call, throwing me errors for the paths that use them right.

```
"C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe" -fdiagnostics-color=always 
-g C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\Q7\PPA\mpitest.c 
-I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include\" 
-L "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x64\" 
-lmsmpi -o C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\Q7\PPA\mpitest.exe

gcc.exe: error: Files: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: (x86)\Microsoft: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: SDKs\MPI\Lib\x64": No such file or directory
```

How ever, if I copy that command right to the same terminal I get this:

```
gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\Q7\PPA\mpitest.c 
-I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include\" 
-L "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x64\" 
-lmsmpi -o C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\Q7\PPA\mpitest.exe
```

Yes, I tried changing the task.json configuration file to change the path directly to be only "gcc.exe", as I have the path in the env variables.

Here is my task.json file

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe compilar archivo activo",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files\\CodeBlocks\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-I",
                "${MSMPI_INC}",
                "-L",
                "${MSMPI_LIB64}",
                "-lmsmpi",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Tarea generada por el depurador."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Any advise?

Comment: I inserted line breaks so you could see easily, but on the code execution there aren't any

Answer (score 0):

Fixed reinstalling and using paths with no spaces